# Как работает цикл while с указателем в условии?

Tags: c++, указатели, while

Не понимаю что значит строка `while(*str3)`. Как это работает и какое проверяется условие?

```
const char* str3 = "abcde";

while(*str3) {
.
.
}
```

Comment: Тело цикла будет повторяться, пока указатель str3 будет указывать на ненулевое значение

Comment: до терминального нуля в конце строки работает

Comment: @Ildar А кто вам сказал, что значение `str3` в теле цикла изменяется?... нет, у @VladimirGamalyan ответ более корректный...

Comment: @Harry согласен, это мое видение проблемы похоже было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операция разименования указателя *str3 вернет Вам значение, на которое указывает этот указатель. И если там будет ненулевое значение, то условие в цикле while будет TRUE и цикл будет продолжать свою работу, а если возвращаемое значение окажется 0, то условие цикла while станет FALSE, и цикл прекратит свою работу.